# R - Scale/multiply geom_bar counts by another variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to generate a `geom_bar` chart of counts of loans originated in different US states. To do just this, I'm using

```
ggplot(aes(x = BorrowerState), data = loans) + geom_bar()
```

where `loans` is a data frame. However, I would like to scale these counts by the population of each state to make the y-axis counts per capita. I've got another data frame called `state_pops` that has columns for the state names and population, but I don't know how to make `ggplot` scale the counts by the inverse of the population on a state-by-state basis. Help please?

UPDATE: per the comments, I realize that I should have included sample data for this. Sorry! Here's some mock data, along with the suggested joining to bring the state populations into the main `loans` data frame:

```
library(dplyr)

loans <- data.frame("BorrowerState" = c("CO", "CO", "GA", "GA", "MN"),
                          "extraColumn" = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))

state_pops <- data.frame("State" = c("GA", "MN", "CO", "CA"),
                         "Population" = c(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000))

loans <- left_join(loan_states, state_pops, by = c("BorrowerState" = "State"))
```

Unfortunately, I still don't see how I can do a bar plot whose counts are scaled by 1/Population_value.

Comment: Sounds like you should be able to join the two data frames by state name. But it will be easier to answer with some example data.

Comment: Give us data and we'll help you. If you don't want to do that then just use dplyr::mutate to create a new column in your dataframe for the per capita variable. Once you've done then pass it to ggplot. dplyr for data manipulation - ggplot for datavis.

Comment: Sorry about that @neilfws and @Dom! I've updated the question with more details and some mock data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following does what you want (note that I changed `loan_states` to `loans` in the call to `left_join` since that's what you called the data frame before):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

loans <- data.frame("BorrowerState" = c("CO", "CO", "GA", "GA", "MN"),
                    "extraColumn" = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
state_pops <- data.frame("State" = c("GA", "MN", "CO", "CA"),
                         "Population" = c(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000))
loans <- left_join(loans, state_pops, by = c("BorrowerState" = "State"))

ggplot(loans) +
  geom_col(aes(x=BorrowerState, y=1/Population)) +
  ylab("Loan Fraction")
```

[image]